# bootstrap 4 nested tabs: 'show all' button to display nodes in sub-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a list of meals eaten during the day, categorized by meal: breakfast, lunch and dinner, each with its respective courses. The tab contents show the quantities.
Link on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ma0yt7k/2/  (code gets too long to paste the bulk of it in)

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#meal1">Breakfast</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#lunch">Lunch</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#dinner">dinner</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#all">See All Meals</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active fade show in" id="meal1">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills active nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#yoghurt">yoghurt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#cornflakes">corn flakes</a>
                    </li>           
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane show fade active in" id="yoghurt">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                              <p>3 cups of yoghurt</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cornflakes">
                      <div class="form-group row">
                             <p>4 bowls of cornflakes</p>
                            </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="lunch">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#fries">Fries</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#falafel">Falafel</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content table-top">
                    <!--pane detail-->
                    <div class="tab-pane show fade active in" id="fries">
                              <p>4 plates of fries</p>
                    </div>
                     <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="falafel">
                              <p>4 bowls of falafel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--dinner-->
          <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="dinner">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#pasta">Pasta</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#pizza">Pizza</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content table-top">
                    <div class="tab-pane show fade active in" id="pasta">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                              <p>3 plates of pasta</p>
                         </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pizza">
                       <div class="form-group row">
                              <p>3 slices of pizza</p>
                        </div>                         
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>   
             <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="all">
                 <p>gather them all</p>
             </div>  
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to click "See all meals" and get a list with all the `.tab-pane` elements for each of the meals of the day. Basically clicking "see all" should show the panes with the text concerning yoghurt, corn flakes, fries, falafel, pasta and pizza (without the 'children' panes).

I can only gather them up if they are in a single category, or parent-child relationship (like Breakfast where each `.tab-pane` gets a class of 'active' but that doesn't work for the other ones (unless clicked)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way to achieve this is to add an extra class to the top-most row of the tabs. this class will then be toggled to display "none" and the elements inside will all have an additional class of "active show".

```
<div class="tab-pane active **toggle-showing-of-this-class** fade show in" id="meal1">
```

If anyone has another more elegant solution in the meanwhile it would be nice.